# dpkg error installing on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to install the nginx on `ppa:nginx/stable` on Lucid after removing the one that comes from the default sources but I get this error:

```
` Setting up nginx-common (0.8.54-4ppa13~lucid) ...
dpkg: error processing nginx-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-full:
 nginx-full depends on nginx-common (= 0.8.54-4ppa13~lucid); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nginx-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-full; however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-common
 nginx-full
 nginx`
```

I've try apt-get clean, dpkg --configure -a, apt-get -f install nginx-common but nothing is helping. Am I missing something?

Here's the output from `dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\t${Version}\n' nginx*`

```
`nginx   0.8.54-4ppa13~lucid
nginx-common    0.8.54-4ppa13~lucid
nginx-extras
nginx-full      0.8.54-4ppa13~lucid
nginx-light`
```

Comment: Ran into this issue. apt wouldn't configure nginx-full because Apache was already running on port 80. `sudo service apache2 stop` fixed the problem, nginx successfully installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst, comment "chmod -f 0640 $logdir/*" line. Then run install:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Or create file access.log:

```
sudo touch /var/log/nginx/access.log
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst:

```
    chmod 0750 $logdir
#    chmod -f 0640 $logdir/*
    ;;
```

I write small [note](http://www.ooshro.org/articles/73-ubuntu1010ppanginxstableerror)(Russian language!)

Comment: sudo mkdir /var/log/nginx && sudo touch /var/log/nginx/access.log && sudo apt-get install nginx

Comment: test -d /var/log/nginx/ || sudo mkdir /var/log/nginx && sudo touch /var/log/nginx/access.log && sudo apt-get install nginx. if /var/log/nginx exist, touch and apt-get don't run.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It worked perfectly. Commenting out `chmod -f 0640 $logdir/` fixed the isssue

Answer (score 1):

The [postinst script](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-maintscripts), which runs at the end of the nginx-common installation, encountered an error. You can find the script at */var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst*. If you look at this script and can figure out what is failing, you can report the problem to the maintainers of *ppa:nginx/stable*.